# Panda convert string array into dataframe with mixed data types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following string array:

```
["12/21/2012 16:00:00 7.40",
"2/24/2012 13:00:00 2.21",
"10/26/2012 16:00:00 87.20",
....]
```

The date and float values are tab separated. How can I turn this into a data frame with data converted into their respective types? So, col1 should be date and col2 should be float.

Comment: use `re.split(r'\t+', list_item)` to get the items split into separate items. Then you can add them into columns.

Comment: You can use rsplit, df = pd.DataFrame([i.rsplit(maxsplit = 1) for i in l], columns = ['date', 'val'])

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the `\t` to split based on tab. However, the data inside the string is spaces. So here's how I broke it down.

```
x = ["12/21/2012 16:00:00   7.40",
     "2/24/2012 13:00:00    2.21",
     "10/26/2012 16:00:00   87.20"]

y = [[" ".join(i.split()[:2]),float(i.split()[2])] for i in x]
print (y)
```

This will give me a final list as follows:

```
[['12/21/2012 16:00:00', 7.4], ['2/24/2012 13:00:00', 2.21], ['10/26/2012 16:00:00', 87.2]]
```

With this, you can convert it to a DataFrame.

Here's the full code with the DataFrame as well:

```
import pandas as pd
x = ["12/21/2012 16:00:00   7.40",
     "2/24/2012 13:00:00    2.21",
     "10/26/2012 16:00:00   87.20"]

z = [[" ".join(i.split()[:2]),float(i.split()[2])] for i in x]
df = pd.DataFrame(z,columns=['Date','Val'])
print(df)
```

The output of the DataFrame is:

```
                  Date    Val
0  12/21/2012 16:00:00   7.40
1   2/24/2012 13:00:00   2.21
2  10/26/2012 16:00:00  87.20
```